# GCM Topic messaging error

Tags: java, android

I want to let my application to register for topic messaging, but each time I try to call Topic registration it is returning the error below

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid topic name:

Using the method bellow

```
GcmPubSub.getInstance(context).subscribe(regToken, "/topics/testTopic", null);
```

I am using the tutorial on this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging. I will greatly appreciate your help on this error.

Comment: I am getting the same error.Using "IIML" as the group name which is fully compliant with the regular expression provided in the GCM tutorials. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I solved my problem by using an intent service to do all the gcm connection, that is registration , group subscription and other.  check out this link it was more helpful than the one google provides. [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this with the [sample app](https://github.com/google/gcm). "/topics/testTopic" should be fine. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging), any topic name matching this regex should be fine: /topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this error: double check that you conform to the [specification](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging) on the topic name: `/topics/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+`.

The original question actually does conform to the spec and I have no answer for why the error occurs. However another way to trigger the error is not conforming to the spec. In my case I mistakenly assumed path separator characters are allowed and used a topic like `/topics/users/123` to mimic my REST API. The last slash is not allowed.