# Ionic 3 Push Notification Topic Subscription

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have the following code for push notifications using ionic cloud and Firebase Cloud Messaging.

```
let topic = "topics/" + this.user.userRole + "/" + this.user.location;

const options:PushOptions = {
    android: {
        senderID: "XXXXX",
        sound: true,
        vibrate: true,
        //topics: [topic]
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: false,
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
};
```

It works, but as soon as I try to subscribe to a specific topic, then the app crashes when running from android.

When I use subscribe, in the manner below:

```
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data:any) => {
    console.log("device registered -> ", data);
    this.saveToken(data.registrationId);
    let topic = "topics/" + this.user.userRole + "/" + this.user.location;
    pushObject.subscribe(topic).then((res:any) => {
        console.log("subscribed to topic: ", res);
    });
});
```

Again, nothing happens and I'm not receiving any information showing I was able to subscribe to a topic.

How do I accomplish topic subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open the project in android studio and ran it from there, instead of using ionic-cli. 
I saw an IllegalArgumentException regarding invalid topic name.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061612/5808093) helped me solve the issue with regards to acceptable characters in a topic name.